# How can I print more of the dict grid if the alphabet and number are correct?

Tags: python, pandas

In my code, I have allowed 3 giveaway letters to begin with which the user can start to figure out the phrase. I would like an option for users to input the letter and the correlating number, where if it is correct print an additional part of the dict grid.

I do not know if it's possible but I know there are some brilliant coders out there, so here goes nothing:

```
import string, random
import pandas as pd
#User Input
title = input("Please Enter A Title For This Puzzle: ")
if len(title) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()

phrase = input("Please Enter A Phrase To Be Encoded: ")
if len(phrase) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()


if not  phrase.islower():
    print("Please use lowercase for the phrase")
    quit()


#Numbers get assigned to the letters
nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)
code = dict(zip(nums, string.ascii_lowercase))

print(    )
#Giveaway letters 
num1 = int(input("Enter the first giveaway letter you would like: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second giveaway letter you would like: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter the third giveaway letter you would like: "))
#Code for Grid
code2 = {'Number': [[nums[num1]],[nums[num2]],[nums[num3]]],
        'Letter': (string.ascii_lowercase[num1],string.ascii_lowercase[num2],string.ascii_lowercase[num3]),
        }
#'Start' of Puzzle for the user  
print (  )
print ("The Title Of This Puzzle Is", title)
print(    )

df = pd.DataFrame(code2, columns = ['Number', 'Letter'])
code = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, nums))
code.update({" ":100})
HELLO = [code[item] for item in phrase]
print ("Hint: 100 is always a space")
print (HELLO)
print (df)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve here.  You're assigning random values to the letters, which I don't fully understand as you've stated later on that a=0, which would not be the case.

Comment: when it says a=0, that is not the random letters assigned it is just for the giveaway letters to be easy to choose form. What i'm trying to ask is a way for the user to input what they think a letter is and its randomised number, and if what they have inputted is correct to show a message eg: That is correct